# Why are Chrome and IE displaying banner in different dimensions from Firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, flexbox

I have completed a website (using Firefox as default browser when designing) but upon testing this in different browsers, I can see that the sliding banner section of the website is not displayed to the correct proportion in Chrome or IE.

Not just that, but the keyframes I am using to slide the images are resulting in half the images being taken out of the screen. Although I think this may be more in relation to the actual dimension adjustments of the container for the slideshow?

Here is my code which applies to the banner section:

```css
#homepage-banner {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 82vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.homepage-slider img {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.homepage-slider {
    top: 3.5em;
    width: 500%;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    animation: 24s slider infinite;
}

.homepage-slider:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes slider {
    0%, {
        left: 0%;
    }

    23% {
        left: 0%;
    }

    25% {
        left: -100%;
    }

    48% {
        left: -100%;
    }

    50% {
        left: -200%;
    }

    73% {
        left: -200%
    }

    75% {
        left: -300%;
    }

    98% {
        left: -300%;
    }

    100% {
        left: -400%;
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="homepage-banner">

    <div class="homepage-slider">
        <img class="freezeslideshow" id="slideImageOne" src="images/hero-banner/mfprotein.jpg" alt="Protein Deals" />
        <img class="freezeslideshow" id="slideImageTwo" src="images/hero-banner/plant-protein.jpg" alt="Protein Deals" />
        <img class="freezeslideshow" id="slideImageThree" src="images/hero-banner/image5.jpg" alt="Protein Deals" />
        <img class="freezeslideshow" id="slideImageFour" src="images/hero-banner/imaged3.jpg" alt="Protein Deals" />
        <img class="freezeslideshow" id="slideImageFive" src="images/hero-banner/mfprotein.jpg" alt="Protein Deals" />
    </div>

</section>
```

[image: This is what it looks like in Firefox]
[image: This is what it looks like in Chrome and IE (as you can see the images within the container are being chopped off]

The first screenshot is showing what Firefox displays and the second is showing what Chrome and IE are displaying.

How can I handle these sort of prefixes in general? Am I even assuming correctly by thinking it has to do with prefixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it's due to you using relative units like `vh` and `em` for sizing.  In general this is a good idea, but these will not be consistent across different browsers and screen sizes.

he `vh` unit is literally a percentage of the "view height", which is the viewable size of the website.  So `82vh` means `82%` of the visible screen size, so if you where to vertically resize the window, this box will also change size so it can maintain that percentage size.  This means if someone has a browser toolbar showing that changes the viewable size of the website, this box will be sized differently.

if you want these the be sized exactly the same across browsers, use pixels instead.

*( PS: I use MP Assault for my pre-workout, it's great! :P )*

Comment: Thats exactyly what it was Chris...after tinkering with that side of things, it is now displaying properly. And lol, I think I may just need to jump on that supplement too! Thanks for the contribution to my post bud ;)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add the following CSS to your img: `max-width: 100%`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you using `transform` property instead of absolute positioning.
 So your animation would play in the composition layer.

Then your code could be simplified like this:

```css
#homepage-banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 82vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.homepage-slider img {
  width: 20%; 
  cursor: pointer;
}

.homepage-slider {
  display:flex;
  width: 500%;
  animation: 24s slider infinite;
}

.homepage-slider:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes slider {
  0%,
  {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
  23% {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-20%)
  }
  48% {
    transform: translateX(-20%)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-40%)
  }
  73% {
    transform: translateX(-40%)
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-60%)
  }
  98% {
    transform: translateX(-60%)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-80%)
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="homepage-banner">

  <div class="homepage-slider">
    <img class="freezeslideshow" id="slideImageOne" src="https://picsum.photos/800/200?1" alt="Protein Deals" />
    <img class="freezeslideshow" id="slideImageTwo" src="https://picsum.photos/800/200?2" alt="Protein Deals" />
    <img class="freezeslideshow" id="slideImageThree" src="https://picsum.photos/800/200?3" alt="Protein Deals" />
    <img class="freezeslideshow" id="slideImageFour" src="https://picsum.photos/800/200?4" alt="Protein Deals" />
    <img class="freezeslideshow" id="slideImageFive" src="https://picsum.photos/800/200?5" alt="Protein Deals" />
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `width: 20%;` to `.homepage-slider img` should fix your issue. Currently, nothing is telling your images how large to be. Alternatively, you could set that container to `display: flex;` and give the images `flex: 1;`. That would be one less line to update if you change the number of images in the carousel.